# Use a GeometryDrawing object to remove margins and set the size of a vector icon

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to build a GridView with a list of file objects and their properties. One of the properties is the logo of the fieldbus protocol, supported by the file.

After the protocol logos were converted from .png to .xaml, the current UI looks like the following:
[Current UI state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9GGK.jpg)

The example of one .xaml logo file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <DrawingImage x:Key="EtherCAT_design">
            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <DrawingGroup.Children>
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFFEFEFE"
                                         Geometry="F1 M0,601.33335 L0,0 947.33335,0 1894.6667,0 1894.6667,601.33335 1894.6667,1202.6667 947.33335,1202.6667 0,1202.6667 z" />
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="..."
                                         Geometry="..." />
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="..."
                                         Geometry="..." />
                        ...
                        ...
                    </DrawingGroup.Children>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
        </DrawingImage>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Now, I would like to **remove the margins** and make the **background transparent** for each logo on the list.

*What I've already tried:*

- Removing the first *GeometryDrawing* from the *DrawingGroup.Children* produces different default sizes for each picture ([Removing the first GeometryDrawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nikmL.jpg))
- Setting another value for the *Geometry* property of the first *GeometryDrawing* object: *Geometry="F1M16,16L0,16 0,0 16,0z"* still leaves a margin above the picture ([Adjusting the Geometry property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRkC3.jpg))
- After reading the [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax) it is still unclear to me, how to define the Geometry property so that I wouldn't have any margins and still have all the pictures of the same size on the list.

Comment: How do the actual icon geometries look like? Please provide an example. Is there more than one color in each icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the first geometry is an overcomplicated version of the rectangle `(0, 0, 1894.6667, 1202.6667)`.

Assuming that the center of the icon is at the center of the "frame" rectangle, i.e. at about `(947, 601)`, you may simply create a smaller rectangle centered at the same point. Put that into a transparent GeometryDrawing:

```
<GeometryDrawing Brush="Transparent">
    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="547,201,800,800"/>
    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
</GeometryDrawing>
```

The example above define a 800 x 800 rectangle, still centered at `(947, 601)`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But I still don't understand why is the rectangle centered at `(947, 601)`, if the values of your _Rect_  property are "**547**,**201**,800,800".

Comment: The values are (origin-x, origin-y, width, height). Add width/2 to origin-x and height/2 to origin-y to get the center.